# Wordpress - Custom directory with registered menus

Tags: wordpress

I have a website example.com and I want to create a sub directory for it like this example.com/sub/, I have done it by putting a sub folder in root of wordpress where admin/includes/content and htaccess file is.

But now I want to add a menu and register it with wordpress, is it possible to do it? What core files and things I need to include for this?

Please help, thank you.

Comment: In what context do you need a sub directory for it? Do you need it like just a different page or a completely different site?

Comment: It will be a completely different website, but i still want to manage it through the admin panel like editing menus, changing names, etc, possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but you can't just move the site there. You need a separate installation of wordpress files there. Like everything, core files and new database. Run the installation again. 

Or you can duplicate your current site to the new location using a Duplicator plugin.

Comment: How can I access /greenpawn.php file without creating folder in root directory? Can you guide me. I have the page ready but it wont load and give me a 404